# Javascript inheritence .Why does my class share nested member data?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty with the following inheritance code that I read in Crockfords book.

When I create two instances of a Column object the "this.name" member data is different in each instance, as I would have expected.

However, when I use nested member data "this.model.name" it is always shared among the instances.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

```
var BaseColumn = function() {
   this.model = {};
   this.model.name = "";
   this.name="";
};

var Column = function (name) {
   this.model.name = name;
   this.name = name;
};

Column.prototype = new BaseColumn();

var col1 = new Column("Column1");
var col2 = new Column("Column2");

alert(col1.name);          //Returns "Column1"
alert(col2.name);          //Returns "Column2"
alert(col1.model.name);    //Returns "Column2"
alert(col2.model.name);    //Returns "Column2"
```

Comment: there is only one `model` object - the BaseColumn one - and both Columns refer to it - what is expected result?

Comment: oh, ok so would creating a new model in Column function helps? `this.model = { name: name }` instead of `this.model.name = name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by [James Wilkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29990460/227299) is correct. There is only one instance of `BaseColumn` being created and it's shared by all instances of `Column`s through `Column.prototype`

However, it's worth noting that your way of establishing inheritance is incorrect.  There's no need to instantiate a parent just to set up inheritance, and you need to call the parent's constructor from your constructor.

See my posts at http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html and http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2014/10/understanding-prototypical-inheritance.html for further details

The following example works fine.

```js
    var BaseColumn = function() {
      this.model = {};
      this.model.name = "";
      this.name = "";
    };

    var Column = function(name) {
      // Call the parent's constructor, a new model object will be created
      // instead of using a shared one from the prototype
      BaseColumn.apply(this);
      this.model.name = name;
      this.name = name;
    };

    Column.prototype = Object.create(BaseColumn.prototype);

    var col1 = new Column("Column1");
    var col2 = new Column("Column2");

    console.log(col1.name); //Returns "Column1"
    console.log(col2.name); //Returns "Column2"
    console.log(col1.model.name); //Returns "Column1"
    console.log(col2.model.name); //Returns "Column2"
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. I thought that  Column.prototype = new BaseColumn(); created a new instance every time i created an instance of a column. Thanks for you great help.

Answer (score 3):

This is because every instance of `Column` will have a reference to the SAME `model` object in the prototype.  Creating the second `Column` overwrites the previous value of `model.name`.

Let's look at your code more closely to see why you are getting what you are:

```
var BaseColumn = function() {
   this.model = {};
   this.model.name = "";
   this.name="";
};
```

This creates a type `BaseColumn` constructor that will create properties `model` and `name` on the new object when invoked using `new`.

```
var Column = function (name) {
   this.model.name = name;
   this.name = name;
};
```

This creates a type `Column` constructor that will fail.  If you called `new Column()` now, it would fail on `this.model` (at this moment).

```
Column.prototype = new BaseColumn();
```

This REPLACES the existing prototype with a NEW prototype created from a new instance of `BaseColumn`.  This object contains the properties I mentioned above for this type, and the property values will be SHARED across ALL `Column` objects.  Why?  Because if the local `Column` instance (`col1` or `col2`) doesn't contain a property, the prototype chain is searched for one.  Since all `Column` instances shared the same prototype, they all end up referencing the same values.

```
var col1 = new Column("Column1");
```

Did you know that at this point, `Column.prototype.model.name == "Column1"`?

```
var col2 = new Column("Column2");
```

`Column.prototype.model.name` is now  "Column2"`.  You see, the prototype is NOT duplicated.  It is SHARED.

If the desire is to have one model per instance, you will have to construct a new `model` object for each new `Column`.

For a better way to approach inheritance, take a look at the answer by [Juan Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991411/1236397).  In this pattern, you are calling the base constructor explicitly from the constructor of your sub type.  This will add/construct the base properties, and should be placed at the top of the sub type's constructor (usually).

Comment: What i cant understand is why is this.name unique to each  instance and this.model.name isn't

Comment: Because anything you put in the PROTOTYPE will be shared across ALL objects created from the function the prototype is associated with.

Comment: Which is why I explained WHY it is flawed. ;)

Comment: The question was "Why does my class share nested member data?" (see title).  This is why. ;)  Anyhow, I made a link to your answer for completeness.

Comment: @James I didn't claim your answer was inaccurate, I did vote it up, I just wanted to point out that what the OP is doing is inherently flawed (but it's commonly used). Instantiating an instance of a the parent class to setup inheritance is a bad practice in general. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Comment: And I totally agree. ;)

Comment: Thanks for you great help and time taken. Between this explanation and Juan's  it really help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of `model` is inherited from `BaseColumn` for all instances of `Column`. You need to explicitly assign a value to the model property to make it unique. The way to can tell is by evaluating `col.__proto__.model` and see that model is indeed part of the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: the `{}` is parsed once by JS and refers to the identical object in each instance you create. To create a new, different object for each instance, just do something like

```
this.model = Object.create();
```

or

```
this.model = new Object();
```

or

```
this.model = function() { return {}; }();
```

However, there are other issues with how you've got inheritance set up, that the other answers may help you with.